# Unable to add certs to cacerts with eclipse-temurin JDK image

Tags: java, docker, keytool, cacerts, eclipse-temurin

We currently use the openJDK alpine image in our Docker builds for our Java Sprint Boot applications that run in a container in a Kubernetes cluster. During the docker build we add 2 trusted certs to the cacerts file, these certs effectively authorise traffic from the cluster to go through our internal proxy and out to an external URL.

As openJDK docker images are deprecated, we are trying to move to the eclipse-temurin equivalent of our current image which is `eclipse-temurin:19-jdk-alpine`. However, when testing our application with this image, we are getting PKIX errors
`PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`.

I have tried both of the below methods to add our certs to the keystore (both methods worked with the openJDK image) but neither work with the eclipse-temurin image.

**Method 1**

```
COPY int-root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
COPY eur-root.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/
RUN update-ca-certificates
```

**Method 2**

```
### Make directory for certs and copy certs in
RUN mkdir -p /opt/certdir
COPY certs /opt/certdir/
### Import certs into java keystore
RUN keytool -noprompt -keystore -cacerts -storepass changeit -importcert -alias cardiff-root -file /opt/certdir/int-root.crt
RUN keytool -noprompt -keystore -cacerts -storepass changeit -importcert -alias swansea-root -file /opt/certdir/eur-root.crt
```

I have found this github issue https://github.com/adoptium/containers/issues/293 suggesting that eclipse-temurin doesn't handle certs in the same way openJDK did and doesn't automatically use the system cacerts file over the temurin cacerts file (I may be reading the detail wrong). Off the back of that ticket this change was merged in https://github.com/adoptium/containers/pull/392 which advises I just need to create the environment variable mentioned with any value and it will behave link openJDK did.

```
ENV USE_SYSTEM_CA_CERTS=true
```

However I'm still getting the same cert error. I have also attempted to use the `eclipse-temurin:21-jdk-alpine` image in case jdk 19 wasn't backdated for the merged change linked above but this still didn't work. If it's a thing then I don't mind adding the certs to the temurin cacerts file but I'm struggling to find any help or documentation to guide me on how to do that.

At this point I am running our of ideas and hope someone can see some errors above or can help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm not sure this is really programming or development, but)

**`keytool -importcert -keystore -cacerts` is wrong** -- it creates a keystore file *named* `-cacerts` in your working directory, which is wrong and useless.

For the 'pure Java' way either use `-cacerts` *alone* (in java 9 up):

```
keytool -importcert -noprompt -cacerts -alias $a -file $f
```

or use the full filename (less convenient), in this case:

```
keytool -importcert -noprompt -keystore /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts -alias $a -file $f
```

Alternatively I agree the USE_SYSTEM_CA_CERTS method should work, as long as you don't change the docker entrypoint. It certainly is present in the `eclipse-temurin:21-jdk-alpine` I get as of now, in (virtual) `/__cacert_entrypoint.sh`

Comment: You're correct on both accounts, the keytool command was incorrect, I've removed ```-keystore``` and the certs are now working, thanks for your help.

Regarding the docker entrypoint, we were running our own entrypoint.sh file which is likely why the environment variable wasn't working. I did look up the code from the eclipse-temurin github with the idea of adding the relevant code to our entrypoint.sh file but I was getting issues around non-root user trying to run the commands and being blocked so it was easier for me (and probably better) to stick with the working keytool command.